# How can I hide the points that are displayed on the plot chart?

Tags: jquery, jqplot

I have the following `jqPlot` chart:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
       var line1 = new Array();
       @foreach (var item in Model)
       {
          <text>line1.push(["@item.VisitDate.Value.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy")", @item.count]);</text>
       }
       var plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', [line1], { title: '<span style="Color: Green " >Number Of Visits</span>',
          axesDefaults: { pad: 1.2 },
          axes: { 
             xaxis: { 
                renderer: $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
                tickOptions: {
                    formatString: '%d/%b/%Y'
                }
             },
             yaxis: { tickOptions: { formatString: '%.2f'} }
          },
          highlighter: { show: true, sizeAdjust: 7.5, tooltipLocation: 'nw'
                //            , formatString: '<b>%s</b>'
          }, cursor: { show: true, tooltipOffset: 6 }
      })    
   });
```

but I need to hide the Circular points that are currently displayed on the plot chart for each value in the array. In other words I need the `jqPplot` chart to show only a simple line without any circular points, highlighter or tickoptions, etc..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To get rid off the circular markers you need to use the below options.

```
    seriesDefaults: {
        showMarker: false
    },
    axesDefaults: {
        showTicks: false,
        showTickMarks: false       
    },
```

[Please see this code sample.](http://jsfiddle.net/Boro/zRhXs/24/)