# how to keep one jqplot from obscuring the previous

Tags: jqplot

My need is to draw a basic x-axis, y-axis plot of several lines, with the lines becoming known in sequence as the user enters data. jqPlot appears to have the ability (unlike flot, at least as I understand it) to add to an existing plot. My experimentation thus far is:

```
$.jqplot('dpCum',[ld.fCumPairFwd[0]],{axes:{xaxis:{min:0,max:2500},yaxis:{min:0,max:200000}}});
$.jqplot('dpCum',[ld.fCumPairAft[0]],{axes:{xaxis:{min:0,max:2500},yaxis:{min:0,max:200000}}});
```

which produces two lines as I want them, except the background of the 2nd obscures the the 1st line. In practice, the data for the 2nd line won't be known until the user responds to the 1st line, and then they're going to want to see both at once.

I've made a couple of passes at the jqplot documentation (it's capabilities are obviously impressive) but how to keep existing lines visible as new lines are added escapes me. I'm thinking there may be some kind of z-axis opacity, but haven't been able to understand it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your problem, I believe, is to use the `replot()` method and paint a new plot with the modified data set.

[This approach is presented in the following sample.](http://jsfiddle.net/Boro/Q8z5B/) Please notice I made only the series with index 0 responsive to clicks. On click on the series' data points another is painted.

---

**EDIT:** The reason I went for `replot()` was that I couldn't figure out how to draw just a single series. I tried [the approach presented by @Mark here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10837537/613495) with no success. He might know better though. I am rather fresh to `jqPlot` myself. Also taking into account that when we add a new series some points might reach outside the current scale, therefore, since [`redraw()` doesn't rescale as mentioned here by the jqPlot author](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/jqplot-users/3tGWOwqBwM0) - though in my case it will work since we reinitialize the graph. Thus, I think if you also will not manage to apply single series draw you might try using the `redraw()` method instead, taking from the doc I think it is less expensive to call.

Maybe actually in this case you will not use `replot()` or `redraw()`, as in the sample I am making a new plot each time. Therefore, it seems to me to be more appropriate to call `destroy()` on the previous graph before we paint the new one. *This is what currently is in the code sample.*

Comment: Many thanks for the reply and the fiddle, and I've learned quite a bit from looking at that. Your solution will allow me do what I asked. However, it appears that it's having to replot what had previously been plotted. Do you think that is what it will be doing? If so, I'll need to keep trying to avoid the overhead of replotting what has already been done as the number of lines will go to around 100. Just for information, the need to plot an additional line will come from an entry to an input field.

Comment: Please see the **EDIT**. Also you could kindly ask @Mark, the author of answer that I linked you to in this **EDIT**, for some advice on that subject.

Comment: @Terry could you, out of curiosity, share with me which method did you choose and how it works in your case?

Comment: Haven't really chosen yet, but I will certainly let you know and give you details.