# How to hide the y-axis label of jqplot bar graph

Tags: jquery, charts, jqplot

I'm working on a jqplot horizontal stacked bar graph. I want to hide all the labels from the `x` and `y` axis. I was able to hide the `x` axis labels and markers but when I'm trying to hide the `y` axis label one entry remains there.

This is what I wants 
[image]

This is what I've 
[image]

The highlighted portion has to be hidden.

You can find a working sample [here](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/TfUfD/).

Answer (score 4):

I did something like this before. Please check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10796450/613495). I think it is related to your problem. For you the important part is the one under the `axesDefaults`.

I tested the mentioned solution on your code sample and it doesn't appear to work when `CategoryAxisRenderer` is used.
Thus, in your situation the only solution appear to be use `jQuery` and grab the ticks and hide them yourself just after you finish your plot - [just like I show it here](http://jsfiddle.net/TfUfD/57/).

```
$(".jqplot-xaxis-tick").hide();
$(".jqplot-yaxis-tick").hide();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can just override the label to an empty string

```
yaxis: {
    ticks: ['']
}
```

Comment: In this case the bar is not drawn at all